# problem publishing with rosbridge suite

Tags: ros, topic, rosbridge, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have run this tutorial (I am using ROS Hydro)
wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/Tutorials/RunningRosbridge
on running rosbridge example.

When I started the HTML page, I noticed that all work expect publishing the /cmd/vel topic. I am getting this error message

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1397113517.026746] [Client 4] [id: advertise:/cmd_vel:1] advertise: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queue_size'

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1397113517.035466] [Client 4] [id: publish:/cmd_vel:2] publish: Cannot infer topic type for topic /cmd_vel as it is not yet advertised

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

I tested the same code on another Hydro machine and it worked, but on my machine with the same configuration, I had the error above.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151501/problem-publishing-with-rosbridge-suite/) by [Anis Koubaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/14671/anis-koubaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-12**:
Can you share the rosbridge package version and HTML code you tested?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-25**:
I will check the problem sometime tommorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Refer to [the github issue in rosbridge_suite](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/102).
It was because incompatibility in rospy between groovy and hydro. Groovy version of rosbridge_suite has been re-released and should not have this error as of now.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0